# setting id for an image in a joomla article

Tags: javascript, joomla

I can't seem to be able to add an ID to an img Tag inside an article. I mean I am adding the id inside the html, but after I save it (the article), the id disappears.

The reason I want the ID to be added, is that I want to perform some javascript on the article, and I need to identify the img TAG so I can make changes on the image.
I use EasyScript module/extension in order to add javascript to a webpage. But I cannot do that if I cannot set an Id to an image so I can make changes to it.

Please tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to your default text filter settings stripping out blacklisted html.

Tags for the Default Black List include: 'applet', 'body', 'bgsound', 'base', 'basefont', 'embed', 'frame', 'frameset', 'head', 'html', '**id**', 'iframe', 'ilayer', 'layer', 'link', 'meta', 'name', 'object', 'script', 'style', 'title', 'xml'

Assuming you are using Joomla 2.5 or 3 - to change this text filter setting in the admin area go to System -> Global Configuration -> Text Filters tab

Comment: How do you recommend I change the filter? I tried to set the filter of "Public" to No Filter, but after that I keep receiving error messages like "You are not permitted to use that link to directly access that page (#435)." or stuff like that, when accessing an article. And the "id" still does not persist. Can you tell me exactly how to set the filters in order to be able to achieve my goal? I thought that if I would install the extension that DOES this (allows adding javascript to Head tag) all the settings would go into place. Or at least there would be some information on how to set it up

Comment: The filter is applied when you save an article.  So change it for whatever level you log in as in order to write articles.

Comment: Even better is to replace the default text editor with something like [CJE editor](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/editors/88) which gives you much more control.